# Laravel - add key/value to response if ids are the same

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I have a contents table with a lot of contents created by different users… I’m trying to verify if a content is created by the user that is logged in and then add a new key value pair to the response, so if the content was created by user_id 1 and I’m user 1 then the response has a field like isOwn : 1 on the content object that is his own, but nothing if the content was created by someone else.

this is the criteria I have:

```
$query = $model->select('contents.*', 'status_types.name as status', 'content_types.name as content_type')
                       ->join('status_types', 'status_types.id', '=', 'contents.status_type_id')
                       ->join('content_types', 'content_types.id', '=', 'contents.content_type_id')
                       ->with('platforms')
                       ->with('classifications')
                       ->withCount(['favorite' => function ($q) {
                           $q->where('user_id', '=', $this->request->user()->getIdentifier());
                       }])
                       ->withCount('likes')
                       ->inRandomOrder();

        return $query;
```

I've tried to use when and whereExist but this return me only the ones created by the user, not if the condition is true.

Any ideas? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to join on the model and make a where for the total query:

```
$query = $model->select('contents.*', 'status_types.name as status', 'content_types.name as content_type')
                       ->join('status_types', 'status_types.id', '=', 'contents.status_type_id')
                       ->join('content_types', 'content_types.id', '=', 'contents.content_type_id')
                       ->join('favorites', 'favorites.contents_id', '=', 'contents.id') // or whatever the relation is
                       ->with(['platforms', 'classifications'])
                       ->withCount(['favorite'])
                       ->withCount('likes')
                       ->where('favorites.user_id', '=', $this->request->user()->getIdentifier())
                       ->inRandomOrder();

        return $query;
```